C++ how to call function at specific times of day
I need to execute a function once, at certain times of the day, like this pseudo code:
while(true)
{
    now = Now();
    
    if(now == 16:00 or now == 22:00)
    {
        call_function();
    }
}

I do use chrono Timepoints quite often, but always for relative arithmetic comparisons like this:
if(now >= prev_ts + std::chrono::minutes(30))
{
    do_something();
    prev_ts = now;

and this won't work because the first invoccation will be immediately, whereas I need it to happen at the next 16:00.
What is the cleanest way to achieve this using C++23?
What's confusing me is I don't care about dates, nor do I care about offsets. I want something which is just a time object, not a datetime.

Forget all this. Write the code you need to execute once and have your operating system execute your program at the scheduled time with cron (Linux), or Task Scheduler (Windows) or whatever mechanism your system uses.

@TangentiallyPerpendicular it's not a separate process. The data (from the function) needs to be available to the rest of the application.

If there's some reason why a scheduled task won't work for you then you need to explain that in your question. Nevertheless, having a process running 24/7 checking the time every few microseconds is seriously bad practice. It wastes processor time, and battery power (if that's relevant), and may not even work if the OS sleeps the process in idle periods.

The easiest and cleanest is still to use std::time with std::localtime_r from <ctime>. That will split the time into hours, minutes and seconds way easier than anything in the <chrono> library. Just periodically check the time and sleep.

Any reason why this is tagged c++23?

@catnip to show C++23 answers are welcome because chrono got much better after (c++20?).

Since C++11 (I think) you might consider using std::sleep_for() or std::sleep_until() (when initiating, work out how far in the future you wish the required action, and sleep that long).   The catch is that they put the current thread to sleep - if your program needs to do other things while waiting, you'll need to do explicitly schedule those "other things", or do them on another thread.  It might be (umm) less complicated to schedule a cron/scheduler task on your system to signal your program when required (and write code to respond to that signal).

Are you looking for executing at local time, or UTC?   It makes a difference as local time is not guaranteed to be regular like UTC.

@Tangentially Perpendicular -- there are reasons why you can't use OS scheduler. For example, I have a code in DLL loaded by another application, which needs to be executed each Friday at 4pm.

This is a question that can be answered in several ways.  Which way is right depends on the needs of the application.

Is the time of day specified in local time or UTC?
If local time, is it the computer's current local time zone, or is the time zone specified by some other means such as an IANA identifier?
If it is the current local time, is the device mobile?
If it is the current local time, does the application have to be up for months and automatically update as new versions of the IANA timezone database are installed on the device?

Depending on the answers to these questions, the answer to the OP's question ranges from very simple to relatively complex.  No matter how complex it gets though, <chrono> in C++23 can handle it.
In my answers below, I'm using function-local using directives to cut down on the verbosity that can be caused by repeating std::chrono:: in many places.  By keeping the using directives in function scope I avoid polluting the global namespace.  However if this is not your style, please feel free to add std::chrono:: directly to those symbols that otherwise require it.
I'll start with the simplest answer, and build on that with increasing complexity to handle the harder cases.
The time of day is specified in UTC:
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

// UTC time

template <class F>
void
execute_at_time_of_day(std::chrono::system_clock::duration tod, F f)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto now = system_clock::now();
    auto time_to_execute = floor<days>(now) + tod;
    if (time_to_execute < now)
        time_to_execute += days{1};
    while (true)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(time_to_execute);
        f();
        time_to_execute += days{1};
    }
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    std::thread{[]()
    {
        execute_at_time_of_day(16h, []() {std::cout << "hi 1\n";});}
    }.detach();
    std::thread{[t]()
    {
        execute_at_time_of_day(22h, []() {std::cout << "hi 2\n";});}
    }.detach();
    while (true) {}
}

Notes:
I've simplified main by assuming the application runs forever.  So there's no need to include a way to tell the threads that it is time for the application to end.  In a real application one would include a way for main to tell the threads it is time to end, and then join up with the threads prior to ending.
I've also dedicated a thread to each time-of-day/function pair so that it is trivial to have some number of pairs other than two.
The time-of-day (UTC) is specified by a chrono duration that can be as coarse as hours or as fine as system_clock::duration, which is at least as fine as microseconds in practice.  For example if I wanted to change 16:00 to 16:05:34.500 then in main I would change 16h to 16h + 5min + 34s + 500ms.
In this simplest case execute_at_time_of_day first gets the system time, storing it in the variable now.  This time is reported as Unix Time (time since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, excluding leap seconds).
The expression floor<days>(now) truncates the current time to days-precision (rounding down).  This is effectively the UTC date and can also serve as a time point to the midnight that starts this UTC date.
To the UTC date is added the time-of-day that was passed in.  This is the desired time to execute the function f next.  If this time is in the past, 1 day is added.
In the loop we sleep until the desired time to execute the function.  Then we execute the function.  Then we compute the next time to execute the function by adding 1 day.
The time of day is local time / Stationary device
If the time-of-day is specified to be the device's local time, execute_at_time_of_day gets slightly more complicated.
// Local time / Stationary device

template <class F>
void
execute_at_time_of_day(std::chrono::system_clock::duration local_tod, F f)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto zone = current_zone();
    auto now_utc = system_clock::now();
    auto time_to_execute = zone->to_local(now_utc);
    time_to_execute = floor<days>(time_to_execute) + local_tod;
    if (zone->to_sys(time_to_execute) < now_utc)
        time_to_execute += days{1};
    while (true)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(zone->to_sys(time_to_execute));
        f();
        time_to_execute += days{1};
    }
}

Notes:
The expression current_zone() returns a time_zone const* that refers to the device's currently set time zone.  This can be used to translate between UTC and local timepoints.  The result is stored in the variable zone.
If instead of the device's current local time zone, you want a specific IANA time zone, then you can change this line:
auto zone = current_zone();

to (for example):
auto zone = locate_zone("Europe/London");

In this version of execute_at_time_of_day time_to_execute is computed in local time as opposed to UTC.  This is done by first translating the current time to local time using zone.  Then (as before) execute_at_time_of_day is floored to days-precision and the desired time-of-day is added to it.  And if this time is in the past, a day is added.
The "in the past" check is done in UTC, not local time, as UTC is known to be a monotonic scale, unlike local time which can jump around due to daylight saving adjustments (or any other politician-initiated adjustment).
In the loop the time_to_execute is translated to UTC for the sleep_until statement.  sleep_until will fail to compile if passed a local time.  This is again motivated by the non-monotonic property of local time.
After the function is called, the next execution time is computed in local time, not UTC.  This preserves the local time of day, even across daylight saving boundaries.  I.e. the next function call is usually 24 hours later, but could be 23 or 25 hours later depending on daylight saving rules.  If this computation was done in UTC, then the next function call would always be exactly 24h later.
It is possible (but not likely) that the specified local time has a non-unique mapping to UTC.  This can happen when (for example) a UTC offset adjustment due to daylight saving skips over a local time, or creates two of them.  If this happens, an exception will be thrown.  If an exception is not desired, there are ways to do that too.  But I will save that for another question.
If this device might sometimes be moved to another time zone, and if it is acceptable for the function to execute at the wrong time when this happens, then change this line:
std::this_thread::sleep_until(zone->to_sys(time_to_execute));

to:
std::this_thread::sleep_until(current_zone()->to_sys(time_to_execute));

I.e. re-query what the local time zone is on each iteration of the loop.
The time of day is local time / Mobile device
If the device is known to change time zones, and one needs the device to keep up with the changing timezones and execute at the right time even right after such a change, then things get significantly more complicated.
The solution below dedicates a thread to doing nothing but checking to see if the local time zone has changed.  And when it does change, a global-scope variable holding the time_zone const* communicates what the local time zone is between threads, and global-scope mutex and condition_variable synchronize that communication in a thread-safe manner:
// Local time / For mobile device

auto zone = std::chrono::current_zone();
std::mutex zone_mutex;
std::condition_variable zone_cv;

void
check_for_zone_change()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    while (true)
    {
        auto new_zone = current_zone();
        if (zone != new_zone)
        {
            std::lock_guard lock(zone_mutex);
            zone = new_zone;
            zone_cv.notify_all();
        }
        // Adjust this to however responsive you want to be
        //   to changes in time zone
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1min);
    }
};

All this function does is wake up every once in awhile and see if the return from current_zone() has changed.  If it has, it changes the global zone variable and notifies the other threads with the zone_cv condition_variable.  I have it checking once per minute.  You can set this polling rate to whatever is suitable for your application.
The execute_at_time_of_day now changes to:
template <class F>
void
execute_at_time_of_day(std::chrono::system_clock::duration local_tod, F f)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    std::unique_lock lock{zone_mutex};
    auto now_utc = system_clock::now();
    auto time_to_execute = zone->to_local(now_utc);
    time_to_execute = floor<days>(time_to_execute) + local_tod;
    if (zone->to_sys(time_to_execute) < now_utc)
        time_to_execute += days{1};
    while (true)
    {
        if (zone_cv.wait_until(lock,
            zone->to_sys(time_to_execute)) == std::cv_status::timeout ||
            zone->to_sys(time_to_execute) < system_clock::now())
        {
            lock.unlock();
            f();
            time_to_execute += days{1};
            lock.lock();
        }
    }
}

Notes:
This function must have zone_mutex locked any time it is reading (using) the global zone, which is all of the time except when it is sleeping or executing f.
The initialization of time_to_execute works as before.  But the method of sleep has changed.  While sleeping we want to be able to wake up for two reasons:

Because a day has passed, or
Because the local time zone has changed.

To do this we "sleep" on the condition_variable with wait_until.  If the wait times out, then a day has passed, otherwise we have been notified of a time zone change.  Also it is the nature of condition variables that threads can wake up spuriously.  So the code must be resilient to the possibility that it wakes up and neither a day has passed, nor has the time zone changed.
If the time zone has changed, the desired local time of execution may still be in the future, or it may now be in the past.  Only if zone_cv reports a timeout or if the desired execution time is in the past do we want to execute the function and compute a new execution time.  Otherwise the desired execution time is in the future, and we've either had a spurious wake up or a time zone change that put the desired execution time in the future, so we do nothing but go back to sleep.
In this solution main must be modified to start a thread to run check_for_zone_change:
std::thread{check_for_zone_change}.detach();

The time of day is local time / Mobile device / Long uptime required
Finally, if the application must be up for months and update to the latest IANA time zone database while running, you are out of luck on Windows and Apple OS's.  But one can do this on Linux with gcc:
See the documentation for:
const std::chrono::tzdb& reload_tzdb();
std::string remote_version();

Calling reload_tzdb() will update your timezone database if one is available.  Subsequent calls to current_zone() and locate_zone() will refer to this new database.  Prior to calling reload_tzdb() you can compare remote_version() to get_tzdb().version to see if re-loading your database would change the version number of the database.
One could set up another thread to poll remote_version() and call reload_tzdb() when a version change is detected.

You can calculate the next occurrence of the target times and use std::this_thread::sleep_until to wait until those times are reached.
Calculate the next occurrence of the target times (e.g., 16:00 and 22:00), then use std::this_thread::sleep_until to wait until the next target time, finally call the function at the specified times.
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

void call_function() {
    std::cout << "Function called at " << std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now()) << std::endl;
}

std::chrono::system_clock::time_point get_next_target_time(int hour, int minute) {
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto now = system_clock::now();
    auto now_time_t = system_clock::to_time_t(now);
    auto now_tm = *std::localtime(&now_time_t);

    now_tm.tm_hour = hour;
    now_tm.tm_min = minute;
    now_tm.tm_sec = 0;

    auto target_time = system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&now_tm));

    if (target_time <= now) {
        now_tm.tm_mday += 1;  // Schedule for the next day
        target_time = system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&now_tm));
    }

    return target_time;
}

int main() {
    while (true) {
        auto next_16 = get_next_target_time(16, 0);  // Next 16:00
        auto next_22 = get_next_target_time(22, 0);  // Next 22:00
        auto next_time = std::min(next_16, next_22); // Get the nearest time

        std::this_thread::sleep_until(next_time); // Wait until the next target time
        call_function();
    }
    return 0;
}

